# Details about the json:Array feature of Newtonsoft.JSON XML to JSON converter

Tags: json, xml, json.net, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Referencing this example of using "json:Array": [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm)

I have two questions:

1. Does the namespace have to be "json"?  I.e. if ns2 matched back to 
   `"xmlns:ns2='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'"` would that work?
2. Can the namespace be omitted?  Can I just put "Array='true'"?

I'm about to try to test by trial and error, but thought maybe somebody would know the answer, or someone in the future would like to know.

Not that it matters a whole lot, but my XML is being generated by BizTalk 2010 and I'm using a WCF CustomBehavior to call NewtonSoft as follows:

```
private static ConvertedJSON ConvertXMLToJSON(string xml)
    {
    // To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    ConvertedJSON convertedJSON = new ConvertedJSON();
    convertedJSON.JSONtext = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    convertedJSON.rootElement = doc.DocumentElement.Name;
    return convertedJSON;
    }
```

Comment: With later version BizTalk 2013 R2 and up you would use the JSON Decoder/Encoder and you would not need to do it this way.   In that version the XML Namespace can be whatever you like even though I believe it also uses Newtonsoft under the hood.

Comment: I know, but not possible at this client at this time. :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the namespace has to be exactly what they provide:

```
  string xmlToConvert2 = "<myRoot xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'><MyText json:Array='true'>This is the text here</MyText><Prices><SalesPrice>10.00</SalesPrice></Prices></myRoot>";
  string strJSON2 = ConvertXMLToJSON(xmlToConvert2);
```

As with normal xml, the namespace prefix can be any value.  The follow worked equally as well as the above.

```
string xmlToConvert3 = "<myRoot xmlns:abc='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'><MyText abc:Array='true'>This is the text here</MyText><Prices><SalesPrice>10.00</SalesPrice></Prices></myRoot>";
string strJSON3 = ConvertXMLToJSON(xmlToConvert3);
```