# BizTalk - Putting a namespace on an attribute?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Referencing this example of using "json:Array": [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm)

I want BizTalk schema that will build an XML element like this:

```
  <role json:Array='true'>Admin</role>
```

I tried adding a schema to my project called FakeJSONArraySchema.xsd, and then on my main schema, I did an "imports".  The normal way to use an "imports" is to create a "child record" then change it's "Data Structure Type".  But sets that "child record" to the root element of the referenced schema.  I just need an attribute.

In the above example, the element "role" needs to be in the namespace of the main schema.

If all else fails, I will try editing the .XSD directly.  I was hoping this could be done using the Visual Studio graphical interface.

See related question: [Details about the json:Array feature of Newtonsoft.JSON XML to JSON converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479273/details-about-the-jsonarray-feature-of-newtonsoft-json-xml-to-json-converter/39479498#39479498)

Comment: I'm a little unclear what your trying to do, but to force the namespacing of attributes you can set the attributeFormDefault="qualified"  in the schema tag of the xsd or the Form attribute on the <xs:attribute> tag (the xsd also needs to have a targetnamespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sprotty has said in his comment, set the Attribute FormDefault or the Attribute Field Form to Qualified to get a namespace prefix on the attribute.

[image: Attribute FormDefault]
[image: Attribute Field Form]

Example schema with FormDefault set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Role">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="Array" type="xs:boolean" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However it won't make the Namespace prefix JSON, but just the default NS0.  However that should hopefully not matter as long as it references the correct namespace.

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <Role ns0:Array="true">Role_0</Role>
</ns0:Root>
```